# UV unwrap creates thin representation from imported obj (Magicavoxel)

Tags: uv

I am not sure if I am missing out on something,
but I tried to import an obj from Magicavoxel into Blender, so I can optimize the mesh (reduce facecount, bake texturemap).

I do so by using a remesh modifier followed by a decimate.
When I try to unwrap the model, all faces are aligned to the same x-coordinate, creating a thin line. I am aware of the uv loss that comes from using the modifier, but the new one should not behave like this right?

How do I create uvs without squishing the faces?
[image]

I tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MY3rsq5JGw

Comment: Did you tried to Apply Scale before unwrapping ? In object mode, Ctrl+A, Scale.

Comment: Yes I did, but nothing changed

Comment: Smart UV Project goes mad if you have flipped faces. Try to check it by enabling Backface Culling.

Comment: When enabling viewing the face orientation, every normal is correct (complete blue). What exactly do you mean by enabling Backface Culling? I thought this only affects the rendering?